# PHP: string indexing

Tags: php, string

What is the difference between $str[n] and $str{n}, given that $str is a string.

I noticed that both seem to work the same, except that {} does not occur in any documentation I found.

Comment: I found it in the [string documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr): "Note: Strings may also be accessed using braces, as in `$str{42}`, for the same purpose." (but as stated in the answers, the `[]` syntax is a better pick)

Comment: The topic is also discussed on this question: [Getting the first character of a string with $str\[0\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972100/getting-the-first-character-of-a-string-with-str0).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

They are the same. However, they are getting rid of the `{}` syntax, so you should go with `[]`.

[According to the manual](http://www.php.net/language.types.string):

> Characters within strings may be accessed and modified by specifying the zero-based offset of the desired character after the string using square array brackets, as in `$str[42]`. Think of a string as an array of characters for this purpose. The functions `substr()` and `substr_replace()` can be used when you want to extract or replace more than 1 character.
>
> Note: As of PHP 7.1.0, negative string offsets are also supported. These specify the offset from the end of the string. Formerly, negative offsets emitted `E_NOTICE` for reading (yielding an empty string) and `E_WARNING` for writing (leaving the string untouched).
>
> **Note**: Prior to PHP 8.0.0, strings could also be accessed using braces, as in $str{42}, for the same purpose. This curly brace syntax was deprecated as of PHP 7.4.0 and no longer supported as of PHP 8.0.0.

Comment: The braces `{}` are legacy from Perl hashes, and are being abandoned.

Answer (score 15):

Be careful, `$str[n]` and `$str{n}` give n-th Byte of `String`, not n-th character of `String`. For multibyte encoding (UTF-8, etc.) one character doesn't need to be one Byte.

`$str[0]` – first Byte of string

`mb_substr($str, 0, 1)` – first character of string (including multibyte charsets)

http://php.net/mb_substr

Comment: It's worth noting that **before PHP 5.6** the default encoding of the [mbstring](http://php.net/mbstring) module is not UTF-8 — this can be changed in two places: within php scripts `mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');` -or- php.ini `mbstring.internal_encoding='UTF-8'`

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an older question but I have to say that it is really important to understand that $str[n] is not returning the n-th char but the n-th byte. I just spent a whole day with this issue. There was a name `$name = "Ömar"` and the code retrieved the first letter with `$name[0]` which caused an error because of a **malformed UTF-8 character** (because "Ö", "Ä" etc need more than one byte)

TL;DR don't use indexing to retrieve chars from a string in PHP

Comment: The answer immediately above yours: "Be careful, $str[n] and $str{n} give n-th Byte of String, not n-th character of String."

Comment: I know, but I just wanted to give some insight as to which errors could be caused by that. Maybe someone encounters a "Malformed UTF-8" error and will be happy to find my answer :)