# Get first character of UTF-8 string

Tags: php, yii

I get an UTF-8 string from db, and trying to echo its first character:

```
$title = $model->title;
echo $title[0];
```

I get: `�`

What's wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are several things you need to consider:

1. Check that data in the DB is being stored as UTF-8
2. Check that the client connection to the DB is in UTF-8 (for example, in mysql see: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.character-set-name.php)
3. Make sure that the page has it's content-type set as UTF-8 [you can use `header('Content-Type: utf-8');` ]
4. Try setting the internal encoding, using `mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");`
5. Use `mb_substr` instead of array index notation

Comment: ...and as mentioned in the other two answers you should be using 'mb_substr'

Comment: I know this is old, but the issue is still relevant today. As far as I know, doing all of this is not going to solve anything if you still use the array notation `$title[0]`. @PaulS said "you should be using `mb_substr`", but can someone confirm you **must** use `mb_substr`? And if so, shouldn't we edit this accepted answer to add this crucial point?

Comment: @Niavlys I can confirm that. This answer does not solve the actual problem.

Answer (score 36):

```
$first_char = mb_substr($title, 0, 1);
```

You need to use PHP's multibyte string functions to properly handle Unicode strings:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php

You'll also need to specify the character encoding in the `<head>` of your HTML:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

or:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-16" />
```

Comment: echo mb_substr($title, 0, 1);
Result: �

Comment: Can you post the full string here?

Comment: Also, do you use the proper encoding in your HTML?

Comment: In HTML UTF-8
$model = $this->loadModel($ref->id);
$title = $model->title;
echo mb_substr($title, 0, 1);

As a result: � :(

Comment: and is your string really UTF-8? try it with UTF-16 (on Windows, the default encoding is UTF-16 if I remember correctly)

Comment: I didn't mean the code. Post the string you want to get the first character of.

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `li_directory` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `text` longtext,
  `examples` text,
  `time` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

Comment: Not the query. The *value* of `$title`.

Comment: INSERT INTO `li_directory` (`id`, `title`, `text`, `examples`, `time`) VALUES
(1, 'Акраверш', '', 1321708954),

Comment: echo $title;

echo mb_substr($title, 0, 1);
Result:
Акраверш�

Comment: I see. What is the encoding of the file this query is in? Is it UTF-8? Because I think "U+0410: CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER A" is represented differently in UTF-8 and UTF-16 (though I don't know how I can check it quickly).

Comment: Ignore my previous comment and follow the advice of @PaulS

Comment: `$title="Акраверш"; echo mb_substr($title, 0, 1,'UTF-16');`

Comment: NOTE: If encoding parameter is omitted from mb_substr, the encoding that is used is whatever `mb_internal_encoding` returns.

Answer (score 15):

As previously mentioned in other questions, with PHP, when attempting to get a substring, it doesn't understand multibyte characters (as you get with UTF8 for example).

What the other answers don't mention is that you should hint the encoding you would like to use for the mb_substr

So, for example, I use this:

```
 mb_substr( "Sunday", 0, 1,'UTF8'); // Returns S
 mb_substr( "воскресенье", 0, 1,'UTF8'); // Returns в
```

Comment: Didn't work for me without the 'UTF8' parameter. Thanks!

Comment: NOTE: If encoding parameter is omitted, the encoding that is used is whatever `mb_internal_encoding` returns.

Answer (score 5):

PHP strings doesn't understand multibyte strings by default, the array like indexing will chop of the first byte and if that happens not to be in the ascii range you get this result.

Use [mb_substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php) method.

Answer (score 1):

Unicode is complex because human languages are.

[mb_substr()](https://php.net/mb_substr) is fine for many use cases, but it doesn't cope with grapheme clusters (a combination of more than one Unicode characters that render as a single visual unit). In such cases, it'll extract the first character, but that may not be what you really want. PHP has that covered with [Grapheme Functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.intl.grapheme.php); in particular, [grapheme_substr()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.grapheme-substr.php). Let's see it how it works with a few examples:

```
$data = [
    '',
    ' is the flag of Spain',
    'Árbol',
    "A\xCC\x81rbol",
];
foreach ($data as $string) {
    var_dump($string, bin2hex($string));
    $output = mb_substr($string, 0, 1);
    var_dump($output, bin2hex($output));
    $output = grapheme_substr($string, 0, 1);
    var_dump($output, bin2hex($output));
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

Single characters are easy:

```
string(4) ""
string(8) "f09f92a1"
string(4) ""
string(8) "f09f92a1"
string(4) ""
string(8) "f09f92a1"
```

A flag is a character combination:

```
string(29) " is the flag of Spain"
string(58) "f09f87aaf09f87b82069732074686520666c6167206f6620537061696e"
string(4) ""
string(8) "f09f87aa"
string(8) ""
string(16) "f09f87aaf09f87b8"
```

An accented letter is typically written as a single character:

```
string(6) "Árbol"
string(12) "c38172626f6c"
string(2) "Á"
string(4) "c381"
string(2) "Á"
string(4) "c381"
```

... but it can also be written as a combination of letter plus accent:

```
string(7) "Árbol"
string(14) "41cc8172626f6c"
string(1) "A"
string(2) "41"
string(3) "Á"
string(6) "41cc81"
```