# Access character in a string with square braces doesn't output correctly

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have a string and i want to access `ä` character. But it outputs question mark instead of correct character.

Here is my code.

```
$array = array('ä', 'b', 'c');
$string = 'äbc';
echo $string; // äbc
echo '<br />';
echo $string[0]; // ?
echo '<br />';
echo $array[0]; // ä
```

**[DEMO](http://phpio.net/s/sql)**

Can anyone tell me why?

**UPDATED**

```
echo strlen($string); // returns 4
echo mb_substr($string, 0, 1); // ä
```

Comment: I think it has to do with the character encoding, if you replace `ä` with `x` it works as expected.

Comment: @Celeritas `$array[0]` returns correct value.

Comment: This is actually a duplicate of this question, though it's hard to tell http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13508937/get-first-character-of-utf-8-string

Comment: @Celeritas: question was edited... and `string[0]` won't work for multibyte chars on it's own anyway...

Comment: @l'L'l sorry but no it wasn't, at least not in a way that effects your wrongness

Comment: Sure thing there dunning-kruger...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on your charset, the letter ä is a multi-byte letter. When you access a string using array access, it returns the first byte. In case of a multi-byte ä the returns a non printable control character.

Accessing the array using array-access returns the first element, regardless of it's length, in this case the multi-byte ä.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `mb_substr()` like so

```
$array = array('ä', 'b', 'c');
$string = 'äbc';
echo $string; // äbc
echo '<br />';
echo mb_substr($string, 0, 1, 'UTF8'); // replace UTF8 with whatever charset you are using
echo '<br />';
echo $array[0]; // ä
```

[**DEMO**](http://phpio.net/s/ssf)

The reason is because PHP assumes characters take one byte. But this is not the case in your situation with ä so you need to use mb_substr() instead of the index or substr().

I strongly recommend reading the answers to this question [Get first character of UTF-8 string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13508937/get-first-character-of-utf-8-string)