# How do I get the the first character of an already initialized string in PHP?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I am Considering this PHP string:
`$stringTest = “this is a sequence of chars”`. 
Let's say I want to have a new string `$firstChar` that shall contain the first character in `$stringTest`.

How do I write the program?

Comment: There was no need to make a question for this there are a thousand places explaining how to do it. Here is one of them http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972100/getting-the-first-character-of-a-string-with-str0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$firstChar = $stringTest[0];

This would get the first character of string - treating stringTest as an array of characters - and is fastest method.

$firstChar = substr($stringTest, 0, 1);

This is slower, and takes a substring - retrieving 1 character (the last argument) from the string, and setting off from an offset of 0.

Answer (score 1):

Just do

```
$firstChar = $stringTest[0];
```

Strings are an Array of Chars and therefore can be accessed with an Array Index.