# strings in PHP really an array of characters or something else?

Tags: php, arrays, string, foreach, character

Consider

```
$foo = "abcdefg";

echo $foo[0]; //outputs a
```

So it seems like strings are like array of characters but then why

```
foreach($foo as $char)
{
echo $char;
}
```

does not work and gives following Warning ??

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Comment: The old notation (still working but deprecated) was `echo $foo{0};` I never understood why they changed it.

Comment: @Jacco: It isn't deprecated ;)

Comment: @NikiC: Are you triple sure? I was under that same impression.

Comment: @Jon: I am ;) http://codepad.viper-7.com/X0lgFz (It was deprecated a short time during 5.3 development. I don't know why they reverted it, maybe just an accident.)

Comment: @NikiC: It turns out we are [not imagining things](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885241/php-string-indexing): looks like this syntax was on its way to being deprecated in PHP 6, but the current doc page has no mention of that. Possibly they changed their mind?

Comment: @Jon Yes, in the sense that we (that is PHP and its community) don't want them to be used. But they are not officially deprecated, sadly :( I'm going to ping internals about getting them deprecated in 5.4 ;)

Comment: @jacco I just checked it and its working and I will prefer {} over [] with string since it makes me think it as a array :)

Comment: @NikiC, thanks! I will promptly change some of my code back : )

Comment: @Jacco Uhm, maybe we have a little misunderstanding here: Even though using curly braces is not deprecated, you should definitely not use them, as it is quite probable that they will get deprecated in later releases ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding string iteration support to `foreach` was [discussed but declined](http://marc.info/?l=php-internals&m=130858381502918&w=2). There were mainly two reasons for this decision:

- It makes applications harder to debug. Usually you don't want to iterate over the characters of a string. You need that only very rarely. So if you do iterate over a string you probably just made a programming mistake - and PHP will tell you so. If string iteration were introduces this kind of error would be hard to catch.
- What is a "character"? Should PHP iterate over each single byte? Should it iterate over characters (which can be multiple bytes)? If so, what should it do if it encounters a malformed multibyte sequence? And where does it get the charset from?

To solve both problems there was a proposal to introduce a `TextIterator`, which you pass a string and a charset. That way you can't accidentally iterate a string and the byte vs character problem doesn't exist. I'm not sure though what the state of the `TextIterator` is currently.

Comment: TextIterator sounds like a great idea. :)

Comment: it would be cool if PHP interpreter could have taken care of this inside foreach for us now it seems wired  to not to think string as array of characters .

Comment: You often need to interate by **graphemes** (user-visible characters), not by mere *code point* (programmer-visible character)  let alone by uselessly stupid *code units* (computer-visible character). You can use regexes to step through a string a grapheme at a time using `\X`.

Comment: @tchrist: Note though that PHP aint Perl. In PCRE `\X` matches only extended unicode sequences (i.e. a non-mark character followed by an arbitrary number of mark-characters), whereas Perl goes all the way of matching extended grapheme clusters.

Answer (score 1):

NikiC's answer covers why doing this directly is not possible.

If you want to iterate over a string as if it were an array, you can be explicit by using [`str_split`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php):

```
foreach(str_split($foo) as $char) 
{ 
    echo $char; 
}
```

**Warning:** `str_split` is not encoding-aware, so you will end up iterating over *bytes* and not over *characters*. Iterating over characters is a little more involved, as there is no equivalent multibyte split function. You can roll your own using the regex-enabled [`mb_split`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-split.php), look at the [comments from PHP.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-split.php#99851) for ideas.

There are other answers here suggesting you should cast the string to an array, but I don't understand why that would work. The [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.casting) is pretty explicit:

> For any of the types: integer, float, string, boolean and resource,
>   converting a value to an array results in an array with a single
>   element with index zero and the value of the scalar which was
>   converted. In other words, (array)$scalarValue is exactly the same as
>   array($scalarValue).

And indeed, doing this [does not work as suggested](http://ideone.com/r6YLI).

Answer (score 0):

Even though their characters can be addressed using square brackets, [strings aren't arrays](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php). Emphasis mine:

> Characters within strings may be accessed and modified by specifying the zero-based offset of the desired character after the string using square array brackets, as in $str[42]. Think of a string as an array of characters **for this purpose.**

Answer (score -1):

it is called "syntax sugar".

For example, in 5.4 you'll be able to do like this `echo func()[0];`
That **doesn't mean** that a function is really an array of charactes.
It's just a syntax.