# PHP how to check if variable starts with 'pa_' or not?

Tags: php, variables

I have a variable and i want to check if it starts with 'pa_' how can I do that?
i have tried this but it does not work

```
 $test_str = 'pa_';

 if(substr( $product_attribute['name'], 0, strlen($test_str) ) === $test_str) {
                              $pa_array[]= $product_attribute['name'];
 }
```

Comment: Why do you think your code does not work?

Comment: The problem is not with this code - http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e52dd44d8efb75206bbef1159b2c43c816c413c2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`strpos`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.strpos.php) or access chars in a string by [using an offset value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/885250/318765):

```
 $paName = $product_attribute['name'];
 if($paName[0] . $paName[1] . $paName[2] == $test_str) {
     $pa_array[]= $paName;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just check if  `pa_` is at the first position of the string

```
if (strpos($product_attribute['name'], 'pa_') === 0) {
    $pa_array[]= $product_attribute['name'];
}
```

Try `dd($pa_array)` within the if-block to see if you even put it in the array.
I quickly tried this and it worked.

Comment: Thanks. strangely even though i passed string(8) "pa_color"  to it the $pa_array() is empty :(