# How can I print these PHP special characters?

Tags: php, string, text-extraction, unicode-string, multibyte

I have this piece of code:

```
<?php
$letters='ñéáóúí';
$letters=$letters[1];
echo $letters;
?>
```

I want to print "ñ" or any other letter but I only print � instead, any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [mb_str_split()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-str-split.php) function provided by the PHP language to split `multibyte characters` string into individual characters.

**Requires PHP 7 >= 7.4.0, PHP 8**

```
<?php

$letters = 'ñéáóúí';

$letters = mb_str_split($letters)[1];

echo $letters; // ñ

?>
```

**Live Demo:** https://3v4l.org/sG8nQ

Comment: Solution for PHP < 7 or since 4.0.6+ to latest. https://stackoverflow.com/a/14566547/128761